# After opening csv file into wordpad ,i don't want double quotes for the field name

Tags: php, mysql

When I export data to csv file and open file with wordpad myfield Sr. No. looks like "Sr. No." .I don't want it in double quotes.Code is as follow.

```
        $filename = "file.csv";
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');           
        $array = array('Sr. No.','Name','DOB','Address');
        $header = str_replace('',' ', $array);
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        fputcsv($fp, $header);
        $query = "select * from registratin";
        $result = mssql_query($query);
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
          $row = array_merge(array($i), $row);
          fputcsv($fp, $row);
          $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You do realise what the format for a CSV File actually is don't you? That strings are meant to be wrapped in quotes if they contain non-alpha characters? And PHP's fputcsv() function does this, exactly as it's supposed to

Although you can set the enclosure argument for [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to tell it what character should be used for quotes/enclosures.

e.g.

```
fputcsv($fp, $row, ",", "'");
```

To use a single quote instead of double quotes, or

```
fputcsv($fp, $row, ",", " ");
```

to use a space